# How To Get Result Of A HTML Page With Python

Tags: python

> edit : SORRY THIS IS COMPLETELY WRONG!  thanks for answers <3

hello i want to get result of my html page
my url is here : http://Xantia.rzb.IR/PG/IP
result of this page is client ip but in source i have :

```
<script>function getIP(json) {document.write(json.ip);}</script>
<script src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

```html
<script>function getIP(json) {document.write(json.ip);}</script>
<script src="http://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

and when i use `requests.get('http://xantia/pg/ip').text` i just get above source
Is there a way to get the result of this URL?
I have a weblog and I want to make an API for getting pubic IP
if can I use PHP or Django pls help because I just have python
I'm sorry because my English is very bad

Comment: if you want to get the actual IP address data, then just have your python script call api.ipify.org  directly (but not using jsonp of course!). A simple `requests.get('https://http://api.ipify.org/').text` would return the IP address as  plain text. (N.B. The reason it doesn't work when you visit your intermediate page is because python can't  execute Javascript, only a browser can do that.)

Comment: P.S. The URL `http://xantia.rzb.ir/PG/IP` you've linked us to in the question is not accessible, it results in a 403 error.

Comment: @mickmackusa OP asked if they can do the task using either PHP or python. Which is not really the best use of the tag, I agree.

Comment: @mickmackusa if i can make this api by php or js i can do it but i dont know more about php or js or django

Answer (score 3):

From the [ipify.org](https://www.ipify.org/) own sample code on the homepage, there is a block of code showing how to get the IP value in python:

```
# This example requires the requests library be installed.  You can learn more
# about the Requests library here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

from requests import get

ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text

print('My public IP address is: {}'.format(ip))
```

Comment: i know this but in iran sometimes we dont have access to global internet so i want to make it myself
and i want to make any api (get ip information, get date and time, ...)

Comment: If you don't have access to the global internet at times, than during those times this script wouldn't work as well as it wouldn't be able to connect to the ipify servers as well.

Comment: yes and i want to server do it and just give me ip address

Comment: @MamadLove Yes but Igor's point is that if your server is also based in Iran then it wouldn't work, because the server also could not contact ipfify.org whenever global internet is switched off in Iran. And if the server is _not_ based in Iran, then at those times you will also not be able to contact your server, and still not contact ipify.org. So unless you can find an Iran-based service which can resolve IP addresses then this particular technique would not work.

Comment: @MamadLove However as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60526739/5947043) points out, you can simply run your own IP reporting service in PHP - `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'];` is all you need! It will then return the public IP address of the machine which made the request.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is very vague.
What exactly do you want to achieve?

The request delivers exactly what you request - the source code of http://xantia/pg/ip.
JavaScript is executed **on client** (in browser, after the response is received) and not **on server** (before the response is generated).

What you want to achieve exactly? Receive the public ip address of the server or the ip address of visitor of your page?

For the visitors address you can use in your server side php:

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDRESS'];
echo $ip;
```

If you want to receive your servers public address, you can do something like in your server side php:

```
<?php

$response = file_get_contents('http://api.ipify.org/?format=json');
$data = json_decode($response, true);
$ip = $data['ip'];
echo $ip;
```

Please note that this is just a simple example (which requires that allow_url_fopen is enabled in your php.ini).
Better is to use a http client library (https://packagist.org/?query=http%20client).

You should also handle exceptions - what happens if api.ipfy.org is not reachable?
If this request is made everytime your page is requested, it will slow down the response time of your server. In this case you should cache the IP somewhere - i guess the public server address will not change very often (except you are using a dynamic dns service).

Comment: I don't know php I just have a html page Thank you for telling me how to paste this code into the code on that page

Comment: I think I should put this code inside the index.php file and give it an address, but how?